# Error while passing parameter dynamically in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to show dynamically loaded data from a database into the Crystal Report.For that I've done the following things

Created the following parameters in crystal report

```
EventName,EventDescription,Location,CashsafeSerialNo,Severity
```

Created the following formulafileds in the crystal report

```
@cashsafeserialno,@eventname,@eventdescription,@location-detail,
@severity-detail
```

Eventually the design of the report will be something as follows

```
EventName   EventDescription   Location    CashsafeSerialNo   Severity
@eventname  @eventdescription  @location   @cashsafeserialno  @severity
```

The formula for @eventname is as follows

```
if{?EventName}="CashsafeSerialNo" then {dtHealth.CashsafeSerialNo}
else if{?EventName}="EventName" then {dtHealth.EventName}
else if{?EventName}="EventDescription" then {dtHealth.EventDescription}
else if{?EventName}="Location" then {dtHealth.Location}
else if{?EventName}="Severity" then {dtHealth.Severity}
else "None";
```

The Datatble dtHealth returns the following column fields

```
EventName,Location,CashsafeSerialNo,Severity,CashsafeId
```

Values of the parameters is assigned from code behind as follows

```
 if (Session["HealthReportSource"]  != null)
            {
                ReportDocument rDocument = (ReportDocument)Session["HealthReportSource"] ;                   
                for (int i = 0; i < dsHealth.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    rDocument.SetParameterValue(i, dsHealth.Tables[0].Columns[i].ToString());                     

                }          

             }
```

The problem is that when the report is rendered I am getting the error as follows

```
This field name is not known. Details: errorKind Error in File DynamicHealthReport  
{2229A8C9-B726-467C-9621-44B9FFEED632}.rpt: Error in formula eventname-detail: 
'if{?EventName}="CashsafeSerialNo" then {dtHealth.CashsafeSerialNo} ' This field name is not known. Details: errorKind
```

Comment: I dont know abt c# but looking at error in the database there seemes to be no field like cashsafeserialnumber...check or refresh the database

Comment: I've updated the question(included the columns returning from database table named dtHealth)

Comment: Check the parameters to have the required names you are comparing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the database connection. It is not set and your report cannot read the data. Hence the fields are not available. Set the database connection before to run the report

Comment: The problem was that incoming dataset doesnot contain `EventDescription` column